# How is a boolean extra added with LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING in the addProximityAlert method?

Tags: java, android

In the `LocationManager` class, the method `addProximityAlert` has a `PendingIntent` parameter that I don't know how to properly implement.

I know that the first two params are latitude and longitude and the third is a radius and  fourth being an expiration timer for the alert.. but I'm confused how to take care of the PendingIntent or how it even fits in here.

Could someone give me an example within the context of the `addProximityAlert` method of how to properly implement the PendingIntent?

Answer (score -1):

That method doesn't even need a PendingIntent, just use Intent and you should be fine.